# Bind route parameter & values from json body to the model

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a put API in .net core 3.1 Web API project.

URL: https://localhost:44319/api/user/4

Controller method:

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(UpdateUserCommandResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<UpdateUserCommandResponse>> PutUser(UpdateUserCommand updateUserCommand)
{}
```

UpdateUserCommand model:

```
 public class UpdateUserCommand : IRequest<UpdateUserCommandResponse>
 {
      [FromRoute(Name = "id")]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
      public string LastName { get; set; }        
 }
```

Is it possible to populate Id in model from the URL & rest of the fields from the json body? Right now, Id remain 0
I would also like to not include the attribute right in the model, since the same

--- Updated Code -----

```
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(UpdateUserCommandResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UpdateUserCommandResponse>> PutUser(UpdateUserCommand updateUserCommand)
        {
            var response = await _mediator.Send(updateUserCommand);
            return Ok(response);
        }

       public class UpdateUserCommand : IRequest<UpdateUserCommandResponse>
       {
            //[FromRoute]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [FromForm]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [FromForm]
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be working properly without any attributes at all if you select Content-Type

```
application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
//or  
multipart/form-data
```

or  if you still have some problem you can try this

```
      public int Id { get; set; }
      [FromForm]
      public string FirstName { get; set; }
       [FromForm]
      public string LastName { get; set; }
```

if you select Content-Type

```
application/json
```

you will have to change your action

```
[HttpPut("{id}")]
... PutUser( int id, [FromBody] UpdateUserCommand updateUserCommand)
{}
```

and IMHO remove [ProducesResponseType(typeof(UpdateUserCommandResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)] . I can't see what do you need it for

Comment: I had figured out the last option as you suggested here. Worked. but then I have to manually assign id to the model. If I set Content-Type to urlencoded or multipart, model is always null

Comment: @Jay You have to remove [FromBody] if you use  urlencoded or multipart.

Comment: @Jay Post the code you are using to get API data

Comment: This is the method signature. There is no attribute in model class & Content-Type is multipart/form-data. model remains null.

" public async Task<ActionResult<UpdateUserCommandResponse>> PutUser(UpdateUserCommand updateUserCommand) " 

If I set Content-Type=x-www-form-urlencoded, then I get Unsupported Media Type error

Comment: @Jay Pls post the code you are using. I would like to see how  you are adding content

Comment: @Jay I updated my answer.

Comment: Tried adding [FromForm] attr. still no luck. The ProduceResponseType attribute is for swagger.

Comment: @Jay post your code

Comment: added new code in my post. For sending request, I tried all three content types one by one. I see object only when content-type is application/json (in which id field is zero) I tried to toggle the [FromRoute] attribute for Id. For other two content types, request is null.

Comment: @Jay I need your code where are you trying to call the API Arre you using ajax or http client?

Comment: I am using postman. There I set content-type & json body.

Comment: @j All my conde was tested using postman and works properly.

Comment: I created new app from scratch, just to try this out but still didn't work.  Now, this is my method signature "[HttpPut("{id}")] public IActionResult CreateEmployee(Employee employee)"  Employee Class has 3 properties, Id, Name, Address. Name & Address has [FromBody] attribute.  My request body : { "name": "Jay", "address": "Test" }. If it is not too much trouble, would you mind adding your request in answer?

Comment: @Jay You should not use frombody attribute at all, it will never work as I explained already. You don' t  need  to use any attribute at all. Just in postman select application/x-www-form-urlencoded  and add  2 key value pairs (name and address). Your url should  ...createEmployee/4 for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238855/discussion-between-jay-and-serge).